# JSP to return value to ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I want that jsp page that i called on ajax call to return a flag value 0 or 1 depending on my jsp code part.So to get that value I did something like this in ajax call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#photo').photobooth().on("image", function (event, dataUrl) {
        alert(dataUrl); 
        //alert($('#mygroupuserid'));
        //alert(document.Clickpictures.OwnerId.value);
        //alert(imgdata);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'uploadwebcamimage.jsp',
            type: "POST",

            data: {
                encodeimg: dataUrl,
                OwnerId: document.Clickpictures.OwnerId.value,
                OwnerPhone: document.Clickpictures.OwnerPhone.value,
                mobilepass: document.Clickpictures.mobilepass.value,
                emailpass: document.Clickpictures.emailpass.value,
                mypassword: document.Clickpictures.mypassword.value,
                mygroupuserid: document.Clickpictures.mygroupuserid.value

            },
            error : function(){ 
                alert('Error'); 
            },
            success: function(msg){
                //alert((msg));
                    $('#message').html(msg);
            }
        });

        $("#gallery").show().html('<img src="' + dataUrl + '" >');
        var value=document.getElementById("message").innerHTML;
        alert(value);
        if(value==true){
            alert("Face Detection Success");
        }
        else if(value==false){
            alert("Face Detection Unsuccessful");
        }
        });
 });
```

And in the jsp part i only did :

```
<%
    if(flag==true){

    out.println(flag);
    }

    else if(flag==false){

    out.println(flag);

    }%>
```

How to get this value in my javascript ajax call.I want to store this value as i need to make decision based on this value.

At present the msg that is being displayed on ajax success is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>    
    true
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Return a json from the JSP page.

Set the response as json..

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline");
```

In the AJAX success get the boolean value from json and use it...

**Update:**

Return the `flag` value in a `div` and use that div `id` to get the flag value.

```
out.println("<div id='flag'>"+flag+"</div>");
```

In the javascript use like this...

```
$("#message").find("#flag").html();
```

Comment: Actually I dont think its of use.I am returning only a flag value so i set it in a div tage of my presnt page that is making ajax call like this : success: function(msg){
                    
                        $('#message').html(msg);
                }But the problem is that how to use this set value in my javascript?

Comment: See i edited my post.See the success part of ajax call and below it.I had taken a divison in html with id=message.But when i print the alert(value) It reutrns blank.What can be the reason?